# Starting another activity from a thread class

Tags: android, multithreading

This is my first time creating an Android game. The game runs though a SurfaceView.

This is the SurfaceView

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    private GameThread game_thread;

    public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        SurfaceHolder sh = getHolder();
        sh.addCallback(this);
        setFocusable(true);

        game_thread = new GameThread(sh, context, new Handler());
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        game_thread.start();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        game_thread.stop();
    }
}
```

The thread that runs the game is something like this.

```
public class GameThread extends Thread
{
    public GameThread(SurfaceHolder sh_arg, Context c, Handler h)
    {
        sh = sh_arg;
        context = c;
    }

    @Overide
    public void run()
    {
        super.run();
        while(!dead)
        {
            // Update here
        }
        // Game Over. Start another activity from here to show player score.
    }
}
```

So far, the only way I've managed to get it to start another activity is by adding this after the loop.

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, GameOver.class));
```

The activity does actually start and is displayed but freezes and results in a ANR.

I'm guessing that starting an activity from a thread isn't really a good idea and there are better alternative ways.

Comment: If the activity freezes you should post code related to the activity, not code related to other random classes

Comment: I would advice before running the new Activity (I would do this via Intent), to stop your thread from running, as this may be what is causing the page to Crash as its still trying to run the thread, however cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate and start the thread, you do it from the main thread, which also the UI thread. With that, you have a UI thread and a background thread. Now, when you want to launch another UI thread (by starting another activity) from the second thread, because you already have another Activity with the UI thread, you get problem. You can't have two Activities running at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
    ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

    public void run()
    {
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, GameOver.class));
    } 
    });
```